# Why is my Javascript for loop not looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to write a for loop that splits an array (parameter: arr) into sub-arrays of a given size (parameter: size), but it seems to be exiting the for loop early/not actually looping back in.

This code should return `[['a', 'b'] ['c', 'd']]`, but right now is only returning `[['a', 'b']]`.

I've tried researching but I can't pinpoint what in my code is stopping the loop from going back through the array.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [
    []
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr[0].push(arr.shift(arr.slice(i, size)));
  }
  return newArr;
}

//calling the function:
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
```

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Do you want `[['a', 'b'] ['c', 'd']]` or `[[['a', 'b'] ['c', 'd']]]`? You're pushing the slices onto `newArr[0]`, not `newArr`, so everything should be nested an additional level.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `while` loop and check the position against the length of the array.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(array, size) {
    var result = [],
        i = 0;

    while (i < array.length) {
        result.push(array.slice(i, i += size));
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop increment `i` with `size`. On each iteration slice an array of length `size` (between `i` and `i + size`), and push it to `newArr`:

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
  }
  return newArr;
}

//calling the function:
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes total sense!

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the array while you're looping over it, because `arr.shift()` removes the first element from the array and returns that. You're pushing that removed element onto `newArr[0]`, not the slice.

So on the first iteration of the loop, `arr` is:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

You push `'a'` onto the result array, remove it from `arr`, and increment `i`.

On the next iteration, `arr` is

```
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

You push `'b'` onto the result array, remove it from `arr`, and increment `i`.

On the next iteration, `arr` is

```
['c', 'd']
```

`i` is now `2`, which is not less than `arr.length`, so the loop ends.

There's no reason to use `arr.shift()`, just use `arr.slice()` to get the chunks. You need to iterate by the chunk size, not 1. And the second argument to `slice()` is the end position (non-inclusive), not the size, so you need to add `i + size`.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [
    []
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
    newArr[0].push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
  }
  return newArr;
}

//calling the function:
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
```